# Validate date that is in three separate input fields for Month, Day, and Year

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm working on building a WebForm that has a set of Date of Birth fields at the bottom. This DOB is actually separated into three fields for **Month**, **Day**, and **Year** per the design of the page. We need to validate that the user is at least 13 years old when submitting the form.

If I had a single `TextBox`, this would be easy with a `RangeValidator` as such:

```
rvDOB.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-13).ToShortDateString();
rvDOB.MinimumValue = DateTime.MinValue.ToShortDateString();
```

The issue is that I do not have a single `TextBox` but three separate ones. How can I accomplish this check for at least 13 years with having three separate `TextBox` controls?

One approach I tried was to create an additional `TextBox` and when the form submission click event is raised, combine the three fields into the single textbox and validate on that. This did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to have an event fire after a value has been entered into each box, and then place some logic in that event which will validate the users age once each of the boxes has data in them.

```
delegate(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    if (!box1.Text.IsNullOrEmpty() &&
        !box2.Text.IsNullOrEmpty() &&
        !box3.Text.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
        // Validate the user is at least 13
    }
}
```